# Jquery Dialog Box inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

Is it okay to have a jquery dialog box inside bootstrap modal? I'm trying to display a successful update message inside my modal. I want to use jquery dialog box instead of alert so is it possible?

I have an iframe in my modal so here is the iframe:

```
   <div id="content">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="location.reload();"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                     <h4 style="color: black;"></h4>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/tablestyles2.css'); ?>">-->
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Employees</legend>
        <form action="edit_delete_employees1" method="POST" name="frm_editemployees" id="frm_editemployees">
        <table id="tbl_editemp">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="employeees[txt_editemployeefname]" id="txt_editemployeefname" value="<?php echo $employees->FirstName ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="employeees[txt_editemployeelname]" id="txt_editemployeelname" value="<?php echo $employees->LastName ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
                <td>Middle Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="employeees[txt_editemployeemname]" id="txt_editemployeemname" value="<?php echo $employees->MiddleName ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="employeees[txt_empID]" name="txt_empID" id="txt_empID" value="<?php echo $employees->ID ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Department:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="cbo_editempdepartment" name="employeees[cbo_editempdepartment]" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option><?php echo $employees->Department ?></option>
                        <option>MIS</option>
                        <option>Dev</option>
                        <option>Recruitment</option>
                        <option>Human Resource</option>
                        <option>Accounting</option>
                        <option>Sales</option>
                        <option>Server</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editempaddress" name="employeees[txt_editempaddress]" value="<?php echo $employees->Address ?>" maxlength="100"/></td>
                <td>Email Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editempemail" name="employeees[txt_editempemail]" value="<?php echo $employees->EmailAddress ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact Number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editempcontact" name="employeees[txt_editempcontact]" value="<?php echo $employees->ContactNumber ?>" maxlength="50"/></td>
                <td>Status:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="cbo_editempstatus" name="employeees[cbo_editempstatus]" style="width: 100%;" >
                        <option><?php echo $employees->Status ?></option>
                        <option>Active</option>
                        <option>Inactive</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="btn_editemp" name="btn_editemp" class="btn_editemp btn-info btn-sm" onclick="validate_editemp();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></span>&nbsp;Update</button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" id="btn_deleteemp" name="btn_deleteemp" class="btn_deleteemp btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="validate_deleteemp();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <input type="hidden" id="ninja40" name="ninja40" value=""/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>

</div>
```

I've tried putting a jquery-ui dialog box but when I saved it the dialog box pops up in the back of the modal. I hope you can help me on this one. Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: try adding a style on your jquery-ui div, using its id or class with `z-index:999`

Comment: I need to display the dialog box in front of the modal. I've tried your suggestion and the .append but that doesn't work also.

Comment: by default bootstrap;s modal has a z-index of 999 i think you should change that to `998` or do it on the jquery-ui initialization
`$('bootstrap div').css('z-index','998');` and  `$('jquery modal div').css('z-index',999);`

Comment: I've tried your code but, it just turn the screen black. Seems like the jquery-ui dialog is loading but it doesn't pop-up.